# Do all IPFS requests go through a public gateway?

Tags: ipfs

I initialized a local directory with `ipfs add -r .` and was able to access it through https://ipfs.io/ipfs gateway using the hash.

I was also able to get the files from another node using `ipfs get -o <file-name> <hash>`

Is the file served through the ipfs.io gateway or through local gateways of other decentralized participating nodes?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: No**

The go/js-ipfs CLIs will not make any HTTP related requests, to public gateways or otherwise, when you perform an `ipfs get`

Gateways, public or local, are just a convenient way of bridging the IPFS protocol stack with the standard experience of performing an HTTP request for some data. A local gateway will let you use standard HTTP based applications (e.g. web browsers, curl, etc.) while still utilizing your locally running IPFS daemon under the hood. On the other hand, the public gateways let you use standard HTTP based applications while using someone else's (i.e. publicly run infrastructure's) IPFS daemon under the hood.

The main utility of the public gateways is making content that peers have in the public IPFS network available over HTTP to people and applications that are not able to run IPFS.